# GPU memory increasing with each run until Cuda Memory Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, keras

I am using a server with eight GTX 1080 on it to train my neural nets with Keras. I have different network architectures and different training data, so I have to call my script for learning often.

After doing that a couple of times successfully some GPUs gave me a CUDA_OUT_OF_MEMORY_ERROR. Slowly but surely all 8 GPUs striked to train.
I listed the running processes with `sudo nvidia-smi` and killed my still running python processes. But after that: no change.

I also called the python garbage collector with `gc.collect()`, the Keras functions `K.clear_session()` and `del model` in my script with no improvement. I still get the Cuda Error and no GPU wants to start training.

Because it's a shared machine, I can't reboot it.

In my opinion it looks like I filled up the memory and now it's full.
Which ideas do you have to clear the memory of the GPUs?
Shouldn't they do it on their own?

Comment: A possible culprit is zombie processes.  These can often be discovered using `nvidia-smi`.  Killing all processes listed by that tool may help.  Otherwise you can try a reboot.

Comment: Sometimes `nvidia-smi` won't list all processes. If you cannot reboot (e.g. on a shared machine) you can try `lsof /dev/nvidia*` and kill all suspicious processes.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I already killed all processes listed by `nvidia-smi`. It's an shared machine, so I can't reboot.

Comment: @Yu-Yang When I enter ´lsof /dev/nvidia*´ I don't see any output. I tried the command on a computer with one GPU and it worked.

Comment: Maybe it's other people's zombie process? You have to run the command as root to see other users' processes.

Comment: With all listed processes killed, are you seeing the memory full when you run `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: @Yu-Yang The memory is **not** full when I run `nvidia-smi`.

Comment: Then it's probably not zombie processes. Are you trying different network architectures within one single python script, or are you executing the same python script many times (e.g. with a for loop in bash)? The former does not release GPU memory, but the latter does.

Comment: It's also possible that some of the network architectures are just too large to fit in your GPU. If that's the case, you can lower the batch size and try again.

Comment: @Yu-Yang I try different architectures within one python script. Each architecture runs on one GPU. So I can try eight architectures at one run simultaneously.
I tried no new architectures in the last approaches before the Cuda Error came. I just played around with my training data. So, I don't think that the batch size is the problem.